# How do I write a list/array of custom types into HDF5 file?

Tags: c#, .net, hdf5, hdf

I need to write some data into an HDF5 file using C#. I am not tied to any specific library but the only accessible library I could find is HDF5DotNet (http://hdf5.net/). I have a simple class containing some data (just using default value initializes to test it easily, normally data gets read from a sensor):

```
public class mData
{
    public double temp = 123.456789;
    public double humid = 223.456789;
    public int chamberId = 5;
}
```

How do I write an array or list of that into an HDF5 file? HDF5 seems too great for this to be a special case, but I could not find any suitable documentation. This is what I tried, following the example:

```
List<mData> mdl = new List<mData>();
mdl.Add(new mData()); // create some dummy data
mdl.Add(new mData());
mdl.Add(new mData());
string filename = "test.h5";

const int DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH = 3;
const int RANK = 1; // <- unsure about this one

H5FileId fileId = H5F.create(filename, H5F.CreateMode.ACC_TRUNC);
H5GroupId groupId = H5G.create(fileId, "/myGroup");

long[] dims = new long[RANK]; // <- unsure, extrapolated from example
dims[0] = DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH;

H5DataSpaceId spaceId = H5S.create_simple(RANK, dims);
H5DataTypeId typeId = H5T.copy(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_DOUBLE); // <- NATIVE_DOUBLE is definitely wrong but I dont know which type to use in this case

int typeSize = H5T.getSize(typeId);
H5DataSetId dataSetId = H5D.create(fileId, "/myDataset", typeId, spaceId);

H5D.write(dataSetId, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_DOUBLE), 
  new H5Array<double>(mdl)); // <- NATIVE_DOUBLE and H5Array<double> are definitely wrong but again unsure which type to use in both cases

H5G.close(groupId);
H5F.close(fileId);
```

Any help or directions also to other libraries are highly appreciated!

Comment: I'd use a [compound data type](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/compound.html). Here's an [example](https://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/examples-by-api/hdf5-examples/1_8/C/H5T/h5ex_t_cmpd.c)

Comment: That example is c++ and seems really not straightforward to port to C# as it involves a lot of memory management and a different library. Is HDF5 really so inaccessible to c# folks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `H5T.H5Type.STD_REF_OBJ` instead of `H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_DOUBLE` works.

This test code,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        SampleH5Modified sh5 = new SampleH5Modified("TestFile01.h5", 5);
        sh5.Run();
}
```

will generate this output:

> ```
> Creating H5 file TestFile01.h5...
> H5 file TestFile01.h5 created successfully!
> Reading H5 file TestFile01.h5...
> chamberId=1 humid=100 temp=80
> chamberId=2 humid=101 temp=81
> chamberId=3 humid=102 temp=82
> chamberId=4 humid=103 temp=83
> chamberId=5 humid=104 temp=84
> Processing complete!
> ```

```
public class SampleH5Modified
{
    private string filename;
    private int count;
    const string dataSetName = "/SampleDataSet";

    public SampleH5Modified(string filename, int count)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        List<mData> data1 = new List<mData>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            data1.Add(new mData(i + 80, i + 100, i + 1));

        WriteData(data1);

        mData[] data2 = ReadData();

        foreach (mData d in data2)
            Console.WriteLine("chamberId={0} humid={1} temp={2}", d.chamberId, d.humid, d.temp);

        Console.WriteLine("Processing complete!");
    }

    private void WriteData(List<mData> data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating H5 file {0}...", filename);

        const int RANK = 1;
        long[] dims = new long[RANK];
        dims[0] = count;

        H5FileId fileId = H5F.create(filename, H5F.CreateMode.ACC_TRUNC);

        H5DataSpaceId spaceId = H5S.create_simple(RANK, dims);

        H5DataTypeId typeId = H5T.copy(H5T.H5Type.STD_REF_OBJ);

        int typeSize = H5T.getSize(typeId);

        H5DataSetId dataSetId = H5D.create(fileId, dataSetName, typeId, spaceId);

        H5D.write(dataSetId, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.STD_REF_OBJ), new H5Array<mData>(data.ToArray()));

        H5D.close(dataSetId);
        H5F.close(fileId);

        Console.WriteLine("H5 file {0} created successfully!", filename);
    }

    private mData[] ReadData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reading H5 file {0}...", filename);

        H5FileId fileId = H5F.open(filename, H5F.OpenMode.ACC_RDONLY);

        H5DataSetId dataSetId = H5D.open(fileId, dataSetName);

        mData[] readDataBack = new mData[count];

        H5D.read(dataSetId, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.STD_REF_OBJ), new H5Array<mData>(readDataBack));

        H5D.close(dataSetId);
        H5F.close(fileId);

        return readDataBack;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi jstreet, I've run your example and when I open the file in HDF View I just get a 5 row x 1 column table that contains very large numbers. I think that it is just storing the reference to the data in memory, which is lost when the program stops running. Is there any way to store the actual data in the file?

Answer (score 0):

One way to (easily) solve the issue of writing a list/array of custom types (i.e. compound) into an HDF5 dataset in C# is through the usage of [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com). In HDFql, this could be solved as follows:

```
// use HDFql namespace (make sure it can be found by the C# compiler)
using AS.HDFql;

using System;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Test
{

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
    struct Sensor
    {
        public double temp;
        public double humid;
        public int chamberId;
    }

    public static void Main(string []args)
    {
        // declare variable 'data'
        Sensor []data = new Sensor[3];

        // create an HDF5 file named 'test.h5' and use (i.e. open) it
        HDFql.Execute("create and use file test.h5");

        // create a dataset named 'myDataset' of data type compound with three members (temp, humid and chamberId)
        HDFql.Execute("create dataset myDataset as compound(temp as double, humid as double, chamberId as int)(3)");

        // populate variable 'data' with values
        data[0].temp = 10;
        data[0].humid = 12.1;
        data[0].chamberId = 14;
        data[1].temp = 20;
        data[1].humid = 22.5;
        data[1].chamberId = 27;
        data[2].temp = 30;
        data[2].humid = 32.3;
        data[2].chamberId = 39;

        // insert (i.e. write) content of variable 'data' into dataset 'myDataset'
        HDFql.Execute("insert into myDataset values from memory " + HDFql.VariableRegister(data));
    }
}
```